# Save what's inside of a circle detected by a Hough Circle on OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, hough-transform

I'm using Hough Circle Transform from OpenCV to detect circles from some images passed by command line parameter.
Now I need to save the information inside from a determined circle (shape and all colors), defined by a specific color.
My actual code is the following:

```cpp
// Read the image
while(*argv){
    images_read[i] = cv::imread(*argv, 1);

    if(!images_read[i].data){
        std::cout << "Image " << *argv << " couldn't be read!\n";
        exit(-1);
    }

    ++argv;
    ++i;
}

array_size = i;

/// Convert it to gray
for(i = 0; i < array_size; ++i){
    cv::cvtColor(images_read[i], images_gray[i], CV_BGR2GRAY);

    /// Reduce the noise so we avoid false circle detection
    cv::GaussianBlur(images_gray[i], images_gray[i], cv::Size(9, 9), 2, 2);
    //cvSmooth(images_gray[i], images_gray[i], CV_GAUSSIAN, 7, 7);

    /// Apply the Hough Transform to find the circles
    cv::HoughCircles(images_gray[i], circles[i], CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, images_gray[i].rows / 8, 200, 100, 0, 0);
}
```

How can I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a complete grasp of your code. However, you can save an image of the bounding rectangle to the circle with something like the following. First find the center of a given circle.

```
// Assuming the variable circle is your output from HoughCircles
cv::Point center(cvRound(circle[0]),cvRound(circles[1]));
```

Then find the radius.

```
int radius = cvRound(circle[2]);
```

Given the center and the radius you can create a new image from the circles bounding rectangle

```
// Assuming src is your original image
cv::Mat boundingRectangle(images_read[i], cv::Rect(
              cv::Point(
                  center.x - radius,
                  center.y - radius
                  ),
              cv::Point(
                  center.x + radius,
                  center.y + radius
                  )
              ));
```

And then save it with the following

```
cv::imwrite("/path/to/file", boundingRectangle);
```

So putting it all together you could end up with something like the following

```
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::vector<cv::Mat> images_read;
    std::vector<std::string> image_names;

    // Read the image
    for(size_t i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        cv::Mat tmp = cv::imread(argv[i], 1);

        if(!tmp.data){
            std::cout << "Image " << *argv << " couldn't be read!\n";
            exit(-1);
        }
        images_read.push_back(tmp);
        image_names.push_back(argv[i]);
    }

    std::vector<cv::Mat> images_gray(images_read.size());

    // Convert it to gray
    for(size_t i = 0; i < images_read.size(); ++i){
        cv::cvtColor(images_read[i], images_gray[i], CV_BGR2GRAY);

        // Reduce the noise so we avoid false circle detection
        cv::GaussianBlur(images_gray[i], images_gray[i], cv::Size(9, 9), 2, 2);

        // Apply the Hough Transform to find the circles
        std::vector<cv::Vec3f> circles;
        cv::HoughCircles(images_gray[i], circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,
            images_gray[i].rows / 8, 200, 100, 0, 0);

        // Loop through all of the circles found and write them
        for(size_t j = 0; j < circles.size(); ++j) {
            cv::Point center(
                         cvRound(circles[j][0]),
                         cvRound(circles[j][1])
                        );
            int radius = cvRound(circles[j][2]);

            // Create a image from the bounding
            // rectangle using the center and radius
            cv::Mat boundingRectangle(images_read[i], cv::Rect(
                       cv::Point(
                                 center.x - radius,
                                 center.y - radius
                                 ),
                       cv::Point(
                                 center.x + radius,
                                 center.y + radius
                                 )
                                ));
            std::string tmp = std::string(image_names[i]);
            // Assuming the files you're reading are jpeg images
            std::string output = std::string(tmp, 0, tmp.find(".jpg"));     

            std::ostringstream os;
            os << "-" << j << ".jpg";

            output += os.str();

            cv::imwrite(output, boundingRectangle);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The key parts including finding the radius, the center, and then creating an image from the bounding rectangle of the circle.

The image inside the bounding rectangle will be saved as the file path with the number of `j` after it.